# Javascript replacements for on(event) attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

If this sounds like I'm asking for opinion, sorry I'm not expressing myself better.

My question is, why is it necessary to replace attributes like `onclick` by anonymous functions? What is the advantage?

For example, I have a web page that needs to be brought up to date, so I need to replace

```html
<input id="text" onfocus="this.blur()">
```

by

```html
<input id="text">
.
.
<script>
  $('#text').focus(function(){this.blur()});
<script>
```

But what does this do? What is the specific advantage of this over the original? I searched, but I couldn't find any real reason, only opinions.

Comment: Biggest advantage in my opinion is separation of concern. HTML is focused on rendering and JavaScript for functionality. No ugly inline event handling

Comment: Another advantage is that you can (more easily) bind multiple event handlers for the same event to the same element. quirksmode.org has a pretty good description of all the different ways if binding event handlers and the pros and cons: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. But to be clear: It is not *necessary* to do this, but it results in "better" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantages are clarity and flexibility:

- Limiting ad-hoc javascript code is considered as a good practice since all your javascript logic will be found in one place.
- It allow you to write decoupled code and "non-obstrusive" javascript, which basically means that you will be able to easily change the behavior of your webpage without touching the HTML.
- You can say than using "onenvent" attributes over event handlers is quite the same as using the style attribute over an attached CSS file.
- using the on() function allows to add as many event listeners as you see fit.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, I just realised, the DRY principle. Don't write the exact same code in different `input`s, but use this code only once in the script. Makes it easier to maintain too.

Comment: @MrLister Precisely, it's a lot easier to maintain and re-use. Your example is a single element, but if that was potentially 100+ elements with a shared class, you'd have to change 100+ attributes if you wanted to change the functionality; with jQuery it's a single small piece of code. Even worse if those 100+ elements happened to appear in more than one HTML page; you'd have to change 100+ * n elements, rather than a single piece of JavaScript that's included in each of the pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons not to use dom0 events.
You can find some of these under the topic "unobtrusive javascript".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Decoupling the markup and the behaviour is the most obvious one

Comment: While the article has some good points, most of it doesn't answer my concerns. For instance, "allow for the possibility that Javascript doesn't run", that will have the same effect in my second example as in my first.

Answer (score 1):

- One good advantage is that this keeps your HTML simpler & lighter and could be loaded and rendered faster while your javascript on the bottom is still being loaded. If you consider performance its better to load HTML (& css) at the very beginning and scripts at the last.
- Also, it separates code from the markup, making everything less
  messed up, more systematic and easier to debug.
- And you can't simply write bulky java script code in attributes it becomes inconvenient, you'd have to write in functions anyway for complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned that inline handlers are a vector for [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).
Keeping JavaScript out of HTML allows you to harden your site and set a [Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)
 that disable JavaScript in HTML.